# Variance Matrix with 'nan' values

Tags: optimization, portfolio, covariance-matrix

I am trying to optimize a simple portfolio using several random weights and choosing the best. When the number of assets is large I get a covariance matrix with 'nan' values because some asset pairs do not have trading days in common.

**How should I treat the 'nan' values?**

Comment: Sounds like the 'covariance matrix' is not positive definite, i.e. not a covariance matrix. Where did cov_matrix come from?

Comment: Do you get NaN values for your portfolio weights? Or during the computation of the covariance matrix?  I'm confused. I don't see any NaNs in the portfolio weights vector $\mathbf{w}$. Are you saying that $\mathbf{w}' \Sigma \mathbf{w}$ gives you a NaN but that $\Sigma$ doesn't have a NaN and $\mathbf{w}$ doesn't have a NaN?

Comment: @MatthewGunn Yes, **w'Σw** gives me a NaN but Σ doesn't have a NaN and **w** doesn't have a NaN? And it only happens as the number of assets increases.

Comment: @noob2 I had several panda time series of asset returns and computed with `cov_matrix = returns.cov()`

Comment: @PedroRio Is there an `inf` anywhere? Absurdly large or small numbers? I'm struggling to see you can get a `nan` from matrix multiplication except through something like `(-np.inf) + np.inf`. Check `w.min()`, `w.max()`. If you don't take the square root, what is the value you get for the portfolio variance? If your covariance matrix is rank deficient and *not quite* positive semi-definite, perhaps $\mathbf{w}' \Sigma \mathbf{w}$ is somehow negative? Those are some ideas but you're going to have to track down what is going wrong.

Comment: @MatthewGunn The problem is when I compute `np.dot(cov_matrix*252, weights)` but when I multiply the minimum value of the cov_matrix and the minimum value from the weights I get a number and not 'nan'. The same happens when I do that form the maximums. I'm going to investigate more but thank you for the ideas.

Comment: @MatthewGunn I assumed that the cov_matrix did not have 'nan' values but it actually has 'nan' values. What is the standard procedure for this? If I substitute 'nan' values for 0 I get a result but I do not know if that is the correct choice.

Comment: Definitely not the correct choice to assume that a NaN is replaced by zero correlation. When computing correlations you should ignore NaNs parewise. I had a similar question on how to compute correlations igoring NaNs (I was using matlab), but it might be helpful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615002/correlation-matrix-ignoring-nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your estimated covariance matrix includes `nan` entries.
- The current [Pandas.cov function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cov.html) **already** makes a best effort to estimate covariance based upon available data by ignoring nan/null values.

This implies that to obtain a `nan` in the estimate of covariance, **you must have at least two return series that have ZERO time periods in common!**

### Your question is ill posed

- What's the correlation between returns of the Dutch East India Company (1602-1799) and Google (2004 - now)? It's an unanswerable and non-sensical question.
- And if your portfolio optimizer says to put $\frac{1}{2}$ your portfolio in Dutch East India Company and $\frac{1}{2}$ in Google, how are you going to do that?

### A direction to move in

If you're going to work with securities that enter and leave your sample, you need to do something more sophisticated than estimate some unconditional covariance matrix with `sigma = mydata.cov()` and using that to choose portfolio weights.

- If the point is come up with portfolio weights for time $t$, it doesn't make sense to include securities which one cannot invest in at time $t$!
- You need some notion of $\Sigma_t$, an estimate that's designed for time $t$.

And replacing `nan` with 0 is not a sensible thing to do! The average covariance term is not zero. Systematic aggregate risk exists and this manifests itself in greater than zero covariance terms.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common problem in covariance matrix estimation, with several possible solutions. One of the simplest involves two steps:

(1) You compute each element of the covariance matrix on a 'best efforts' basis, meaning you take the covariance of the two time series involved after REMOVING any data pairs having a N/A value. (Note that this means each element of the matrix will be based on a different number of observations, which means the resulting matrix is not a standard covariance matrix, it may not be positive definite for example). I assume that for any two time series there are at least a few common observations, otherwise it is an ill-posed problem as Matthew Gunn pointed out.

(2) You "massage" the resulting matrix to make it positive definite (and thus acceptable for use as a covariance matrix) using the routine nearPD which is available in R [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/nearPD.html)

[Even after all this work, a large covariance matrix will be very 'noisy' and of poor quality. You should consider further steps such as 'shrinkage' [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tawny/tawny.pdf) before you use the results to find an optimum portfolio].

Comment: nearPD is nice functionality

Comment: The current version of [Pandas.cov](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cov.html) already calculates covariance "excluding NA/null values" which is the "best efforts" basis you are referring to.

Comment: An example of `nearPd` I did last year: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153022/error-in-quadratic-programing-in-r-using-portfolio-optim-function

Comment: Most "nearPD" implementations just do it via evd and then removing negative entries. There are some better ways (Imo) based on vectors in some hypersphere.

Comment: @will - in that case, if I am understanding you properly, it doesn't sound like those "nearPD" methods will necessarily be a nearest pos def matrix (I assume a Frobenius norm).  I imagine a solution to the actual nearest pos def matrix is a convex optimization problem.  I also imagine it may only guarantee a return of a positive semi-definite matrix - which may therefore just convert negative eigenvalues to zero in an optimal way.

Comment: The reality is though that the values should never be that negative, so the difference should be small. If it's large then you were putting in garbage...

Comment: @will Is the Kercheval (2009) method mentioned here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/what-is-the-best-way-to-fix-a-covariance-matrix-that-is-not-positive-semi-defi what you have in mind?

Comment: @noob2 it looks like it yah.

Comment: While I appreciate your concern for negative eigenvalues and the possibility of portfolio weights that purport to achieve negative volatility, the OP almost certainly has a far more basic problem of having delisted securities in his return matrix!